# Trouble with Javascript show when element is outside of the trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show a div on click on an anchor, the issue is the anchor is inside an element and the div that needs to be shown is outside of this element. There are multiple divs of the same class on the page so I only want to show the associated one.

The markup is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="trigger">
    <a href="#" class="change">Change</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Content to be shown when Change is clicked</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't forget marking as answer! this can be useful for others that coming from search engines looking for the same problem.thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want to do? ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FGgDc/))

```
// dom ready
$(function() {
  $('a.change').on('click', function() {
    // wrapper div
    $(this).parent()
        .next() // .content div
        .show();
    return false; // prevent the link to be followed
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can do it like this:

```
$('a.change').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().next().toggle();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fhmDT/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Got to the parent and get the correct div e.g.

```
$('a.change').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.wrapper').children('.content').show()
}
```

This way you don't have to worry how deeply embedded anchor is, or where is content (before, after) in relation to anchor

Added a jsFiddle, showing divs with different structures, working with same code

http://jsfiddle.net/NWqcq/11/

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean?

```
$(".content").hide();
$("a.change").click(function(){    
      $(".content",$(this).closest(".wrapper")).show();
});
```

Live demo :​

http://jsfiddle.net/dfkge/